# Invalid register options "value" must be an object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

When i try to run my nodejs app, i get the following `unhandled rejection` error:

```
(node:8645) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid register options "value" must be an object
    at Object.exports.apply (/home/igniva-js-vaibhav/Official/project/testProject/node_modules/hapi/lib/config.js:22:10)
    at internals.Server.register (/home/igniva-js-vaibhav/Official/project/testProject/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:352:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/igniva-js-vaibhav/Official/project/testProject/index.js:44:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
(node:8645) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8645) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have solved this by now, but...
I had the same issue caused by invalid registration:

```
server.register(
        require('hapi-auth-cookie'**)**, (er) => { });
```

Correct dependency registration in HapiJS is:

```
server.register(
        require('hapi-auth-cookie', (er) => { }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think thats straight forward. I'm assuming that you are starting a server? The values you pass to it must be an object.
Hapi needs an object to configure the server. Any other value will throw an error

> const server = Hapi.server({ load: { sampleInterval: 1000 } });

from their documentation, [Hapi Api](https://hapijs.com/api/),